# Youtube API in R

Tags: r, json, youtube-api

i'm trying to get some statistics from a youtube channel. That's my first time, and idk how to do it.

i've created an API Key on cloud.google/etc and do have the channel ID provide by https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?handle=@USER. Then, i wrote:

#to call the YT API, i'm using:

```
api_par <- 
  paste(paste0("key=", key), 
        paste0("id=", userID), 
        "part=statistics",
        sep = "&")
api_call = paste0(base, "channels", "?", api_params)
api_results = httr::GET(api_call)
json_result = httr::content(api_result, "text", encoding="UTF-8")
```

#and to save as.dataframe, i'm using

```
channeljson <- fromJSON(json_result)
channeldata <- as.data.frame(channeljson)
```

but the call has no answer (ie no data is getting saved on channeldata)